# Program to count and sum up odd and even number in c++

Tags: c++

Hye everyone, i need some advice on the program that i've written. Why when i count the sum of odd number of 1 to 20 , i end up with 101. But when i count the sum of even number i get the correct answer which is 110. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
int num,sum1,sum2,even,odd;

for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++)
{

    cout<<"Enter 20 Integer's : ";
    cin>>num;
    if (num % 2 == 0 ){

        sum1=sum1+num;
        num = even;
    }
    else if (num % 2 != 0)
    {

        sum2=sum2+num;
        num = odd;
    }

}
    cout<<"Even Number Entered Is : "<<even<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum Even Number Is : "<<sum1;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Odd Number Entered Is : "<<odd<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum Odd Number Is : "<<sum2;
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: What do you think the `num = even` and `num = odd` lines are doing?

Comment: Where are your variables initialized?

Comment: For a easy fix just change `else if (num % 2 != 0)` to `else`. But try to figure out why you need to assign `num = even` and `num = odd`. That's where you're going wrong, after adding `num` to `sum1` you are assigning `even` back to user input `num` which gets captured in the `else if ` part and then `sum2`. Thus sum of even works fine for you but sum of odd has some numbers that aren't odd too

Comment: Did you forget to initialize sum1 and sum2? They need to be set to 0 before accumulation.

Comment: @thebenman I think the summing code would work if the values were initialized; the `num = even` and `num = odd` lines don't hurt anything, they just don't help. Note that the odd one is `else if`, not just `if`.

Comment: @Daniel, yes that's so right. Can't believe I missed that out.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() {

int num,sum1=0,sum2=0,even=0,odd=0;

cout<<"Enter 20 Integer's : ";

for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++)
{
    cin>>num;
    if (num % 2 == 0 ){
        sum1=sum1+num;
        even++;
    }
    else if (num % 2 != 0)
    {

        sum2=sum2+num;
        odd++;
    }
}

    cout<<"Even Number Entered Is : "<<even<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum Even Number Is : "<<sum1;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Odd Number Entered Is : "<<odd<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Sum Odd Number Is : "<<sum2;
    cout<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Giving the full answer without any explanation rarely helps anybody. Unless the OP is taking C++ because it's a required class but doesn't actually care about the subject at *all*, or actually just needs the calculator, which both seem unlikely.

Comment: I would take care of it in future. But all i did here was correcting the above code, which just required a minor change.

Comment: The user can see the change and understand what he did wrong. But thank you for the advice.